# Can someone please explain what `matcher` and `addListener` are?

Tags: javascript, dom

This is a very noobie question but...

I don't understand how this code is working. It has something called the `matcher` and I did not even have to declare this "variable" or whatever it is. Also, what is `addListener`? I thought it was supposed to be `addEventListener`.

The code works, but I don't know how. I do understand how the function `OnUpdate` is working, but I don't understand the part below that.

```js
"use-strict";

lightSchemeIcon = document.querySelector("link#light-scheme-icon");
darkSchemeIcon = document.querySelector("link#dark-scheme-icon");

function OnUpdate() {
  if (matcher.matches) {
    darkSchemeIcon.remove();
    document.head.append(lightSchemeIcon);
  } else {
    document.head.append(darkSchemeIcon);
    lightSchemeIcon.remove();
  }
}

matcher = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
matcher.addListener(OnUpdate);
OnUpdate();
```

I tried searching them up, but the only answers I get are either `match()` and `addEventListener()`. But, what I want to know about are `matcher` and how did it work without any declaration, and `addListener`.

Comment: It's `"use strict";` not `"use-strict";` and yes, you should have declared those variables.

Comment: "*I did not even have to declare this "variable" [...] how did it work without any declaration*" that's what `matcher = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")` does. "*I tried searching them up*" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia comes up immediately when I search.

Comment: [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) returns a [`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) which has an `addListener` method

Comment: @VLAZ Alright thank you. And I know how `matchMedia` works, but not `matcher`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.matchMedia()` creates a new `MediaQueryList` instance this has a method `addListener()`

> **addListener()**
>
> Adds to the MediaQueryList a callback which is invoked whenever the media query status—whether or not the document matches the media queries in the list—changes. This method exists primarily for backward compatibility; if possible, you should instead use addEventListener() to watch for the change event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList

Looks like `addListener` is now deprecated, however the compatibility table has pretty good support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

> In older browsers MediaQueryList did not yet inherit from EventTarget, so this method was provided as an alias of EventTarget.addEventListener(). Use addEventListener() instead of addListener() if it is available in the browsers you need to support.